# Space nodes when graphing binary tree

Tags: python-3.x, binary-tree

I made a program to plot binary trees using matplotlib and it works perfect for small trees. But when the trees get larger there's a lot of overlapping in the graph. I was wondering how I can improve my way of spacing out the nodes in the x-axis to prevent them from overlapping.

I've tried different values for `spacing` but this is the best one I came up with.

```
    def getPoints(self, x=0, y=0, spacing=0, n=1):
        res = []
        if self.left:
            res = res + self.left.getPoints(x-1-spacing, y-1, spacing+(1/(n+1)), n+1)

        res.append((x, y, self.data))

        if self.right:
            res = res + self.right.getPoints(x+1+spacing, y-1, spacing+(1/n), n+1)
        return res
```

The code is inside my `Node` class and just goes through all of the points in an in-order traversal. How should I change the spacing in order to keep it from overlapping?[image: too much overlap]

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the issues with a high number of nodes. I added `self.layers` into the node class to keep track of which layer it's on and added in a check to see which side of the tree it's on so the node's point doesn't go off to the wrong side of the tree.

```
    def getPoints(self, x=0, y=0):
        n = self.layers/2
        res = []
        if self.left:
            if x<=0:
                res = res + self.left.getPoints(x-n, y-1)
            else:
                res = res + self.left.getPoints(x-n/2, y - 1)

        res.append((x, y, self.data))

        if self.right:
            if x >= 0:
                res = res + self.right.getPoints(x+n, y-1)
            else:
                res = res + self.right.getPoints(x+n/2 , y - 1)

        return res
```